# why some people define the prototype property value of javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have seen people doing the following way of coding lot of times but as I usually don't do it and it works fine with me without it, I am just curious on whether it is important or not.
**Note:** I marked the lines I am talking about as `// this line`

```
function Test(name, something){
    this.name = name;
    this.something = something
}
Test.prototype.name = ''; // this line
Test.prototype.something = ''; // this line

Test.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
}
```

Comment: They probably want to indicate that an instance of that class will have these properties. Some typecheckers or documentation generation tools (like the Google Closure Compiler) might need this as well.

Comment: @FelixKling I was just gonna say the same, maybe make it an answer! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They probably just want to indicate that an instance of that class will have these properties. Since we know that properties on the prototype are shared by all instances, just by looking at the prototype we know which properties an instance will have. Everything is in "one place".
This might not be as obvious from the constructor function, which could be a lot more complicated which conditions and what not.

Additionally, some type checkers or documentation generation tools (like the Google Closure Compiler) might required to define any instance property on the prototype.

> I am just curious on whether it is important or not

Regarding runtime behavior, no. The property assigned to the instance in the constructor will shadow the prototype property anyway.

Comment: And then of course some people might just not know better and define everything on the prototype ;)

Comment: Thanks, that seems good enough for my level of understanding of prototype :)

Answer (score 8):

There is a critical distinction here.  To see the difference, instead of a string primitive, let's use an object:

```
Test.prototype.arr = [];
```

This will create an `arr` property on the `Test` prototype.  **Therefore, all instances of `Test` will share the exact same value of `arr`**.  To demonstrate, consider the following:

```
function Test(){}
Test.prototype.arr = [];

var t1 = new Test();
t1.arr.push("hello")
console.log(t1.arr); // ["hello"]

var t2 = new Test();
t2.arr.push("world")
console.log(t1.arr); // ["hello", "world"]
console.log(t2.arr); // ["hello", "world"]
```

See what happened there? The following lines

```
t1.arr.push("hello");
t2.arr.push("world");
```

change the value on the `prototype` itself.  Thus all instances of `Test`, past and future, now have the `arr` property contain both strings.

Perhaps the above is what you originally intended; however, in most cases, what you want to do is actually set the property on the instance, and not the `prototype`:

```
function Test() {
    this.arr = [];
}
var t1 = new Test();
t1.arr.push("hello");
console.log(t1.arr); // ["hello"]

var t2 = new Test();
t2.arr.push("world");
console.log(t1.arr); // ["hello"],
console.log(t2.arr); // ["world"];
```

As for the example you provided, it may prove to be a little redundant and perhaps unnecessary to have the property first on the prototype, and then once an instance is created, an instance property.

Note that when the JavaScript runtime does a property look-up, the object itself is first checked, and if it doesn't have the property (checked by `hasOwnProperty`) its prototype is then checked; failing that, its prototype's prototype, until a match is found or the end of the prototype chain is reached (and a `null` value is returned).

Consider this:

```
function Test() {}
Test.prototype.name = "";

var t = new Test()
t.hasOwnProperty("name"); // false
```

`name` is only a property of the prototype, thus `hasOwnProperty("name")` will be `false`, while in the following case:

```
function Test(name) {
    this.name = name
}
Test.prototype.name = "";

var t = new Test();
t.hasOwnProperty("name"); // true
```

the creation of `t` causes a different `name` property to be created on the instance itself, thus `hasOwnProperty("name")` is now `true`.

Comment: It seems like you answered the "opposite" question, why/when you want to assign values in the constructor.

Comment: Yeah, generally the prototype is useful for attaching *functions* that can be shared by instances, however using it share arbitrary property values amongst classes is probably more of rare pattern. In many cases when we see the same property created on the instance and in the prototype, it's for documentation purposes (making the public interface explicit).